# I need to record a control track (timecode noise) as a WAV file. Can this be done through software only?

Tags: final-cut-pro, pro-tools, sync, timecode

To sync up the Audio Description track, the client requires a separate Control Track, which I gather is an output of timecode that matches the audio sync.  Anyone familiar with this notion, and how would I do this through software?  I am using Pro Tools 10 and Final Cut Pro 7.

Thanks!

Comment: While I haven't had time to read it yet, the BBC has a nice [paper](http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/rd/pubs/whp/whp-pdf-files/WHP198.pdf) on the topic.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful information, thanks AJ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think either FCP or PT can generate LTC in software. Higher-end systems (like smoke) can.

The usual trick is to digitize the LTC track from a beta deck or similar, and add that as an audio track in your project.

If this is a continuing requirement, a sync-locked hardware TC gen isn't very expensive. Horita has one for under $300. http://www.horita.com/

I've written s/w to do this, but I've never commercialized it -- at least since the Apple II version (-:

Comment: It does not appear that the control has anything to do with timecode, but rather with pan and fade information for the track.

Comment: This is really interesting.  The client indicated that it was simply the LTC timecode that is needed to sync up the track, but it makes sense that there should be pan and fade info, otherwise the voice description track would get lost in the mix.

Comment: I knew about Descriptive Video (US term) but didn't make the connection to your need, and wasn't aware that it's been mandated in some situations. I gather you found a solution in BWF Timecoder? Poking around the web I didn't see any straight-up LTC generating s/w, so maybe I'll package mine up for free. Windows only, though.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather, it looks like a pretty specialized form of encoding that would need software or hardware designed specifically for writing and encoding the Audio Description information.  I don't think such features are built in to Pro Tools or Final Cut.  In fact, I could find very little information about any vendors with a solution for this.  It seems exceptionally limited.  I was unable to find anything in the way of plugins for using the mono-track with control track approach that the BBC uses.

Comment: After hours of searching, I landed on this site http://www.one-n.com/bwftimecoder.html  It's a program that takes the timecode stamped BWF and strips out the LTC information into a timecode track.

Comment: As well, in case you are interested, I was referred here after a few hours of searching: http://www.softelgroup.com/audio-description/